# Performance spark: 2 m5.2xlarge nodes vs 1 m5.4xlarge node

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

Would there be a difference in performance if I run spark on 2 slave nodes of m5.2xlarge vs 1 slave node on m5.4x large?

On one side I would say it would make no difference as they end up as both being the same size (in ram and cpu). On the other hand I would/could say that shuffling data between instances takes some (milliseconds?) time, therefore using 1 instance would perform better then using 2 of half the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the time of AWS S3 and AZURE Blob Storage which is elastic computing as opposed to bare metal, technically I see in this example no difference, unless 1) you consider node/worker failure, and 2) you have at least double the local disk - which you do note mention - for shuffling / intermediate stages of Jobs.

This may provide additional insight.